# replace a marker with a string on git merge

Tags: git

In an upstream git repository markers like `{{ my_marker }}` exists. Locally I'd like to replace every occurrence of this marker with a string for example `my_project`. I could run `sed -r ...` after each merge but do wonder if it's already possible with a git hook which fires on `git pull` or `git fetch; git merge origin/master`. I found:

- [https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#:~:text=pre%2Dmerge%2Dcommit&text=It%20takes%20no%20parameters%2C%20and%20is%20invoked%20after%20the%20merge,abort%20before%20creating%20a%20commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#:%7E:text=pre%2Dmerge%2Dcommit&text=It%20takes%20no%20parameters%2C%20and%20is%20invoked%20after%20the%20merge,abort%20before%20creating%20a%20commit).
- https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-merge-commit.sample

But I'm unsure if this can really do what I'm planning.

Comment: You could use a [clean & smudge filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter) for this.

Comment: nice. this looks useful!